# How to make a row from sql table into multiple row?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask about a query on how to get a datetimestamp from the table below :

[image]

To become something like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query, it will give you the exact required output:

```
DECLARE @EMPLOYEE TABLE(ID INT,EMPLOYEENO VARCHAR(100),STATIONS_ID INT,ITEMNO INT,DATETIME1 DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @EMPLOYEE VALUES
(30179,'E13784',38,70077780,'3/25/2017 22:59'),
(30177,'E13784',38,70077780,'3/26/2017 22:59'),
(30173,'E13784',38,70077780,'3/27/2017 22:58')

SELECT EMPLOYEENO,STATIONS_ID,ITEMNO,DATETIME1 START_SHIFT,
(
    SELECT DATETIME1 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC)SNO,*     FROM @EMPLOYEE)T2 
    WHERE T1.SNO=T2.SNO-1
)END_SHIFT
 FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC)SNO,* FROM @EMPLOYEE) T1
```

output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--EMPLOYEENO    STATIONS_ID ITEMNO  START_SHIFT END_SHIFT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
E13784  38  70077780    2017-03-25 22:59:00.000 2017-03-26 22:59:00.000
E13784  38  70077780    2017-03-26 22:59:00.000 2017-03-27 22:58:00.000
E13784  38  70077780    2017-03-27 22:58:00.000 NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! since I am using the real table now, I can see I got the infinity executing :D. However, this give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then the [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) analytic function makes it fairly straightforward to generate the result you want:

```
SELECT employeeNo, stations_id, itemno, datetime AS [Start Shirt],
       LEAD(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS [End Shift]
FROM yourTable
```

If running the above gives you a built in function error, you can try changing the compatibility level of your database via this:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourDBName
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: its sql server 2014